# Creating a dynamic route that sends to dynamic .to() in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I would like to create an app that the route will be decided on run time in both ends, both from() and to() and the processing in between remains the same

My example:
I would like to have a configuration file in my app, and there i will tell the source and destination, while the mid job remains the same.

I will always perform a job as a process() in all my solutions

The tricky part is making both ends dynamic...

Ive read about Recipient List, toD(), choice().when()

I cant seem to make this work.

My goal is to have some sort of a RouteFactory that will set the camelContext accordingly (let say my options are kafka or rabbitMq)

Once i got my kafka/rabbitMQ route, now my processor() will set an header in the message that will tell me if my to() needs to go to kafka/RabbitMq

i managed to do only one end of this problem, either my from() is dynamic or my to() is dynamic...

But i cant seem to make both of them dynamic

I created a factory like so:

```
 public RouteBuilder RouteFactory(String type, Processor processor)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "kafka":
            return new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    // setup kafka component with the brokers
                    KafkaComponent kafka = new KafkaComponent();
                    kafka.setBrokers("{{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}");
                    getContext().addComponent("kafka", kafka);
                    log.info("About to start route: Kafka Server -> Log ");

                    from("kafka:{{consumer.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}"
                            + "&maxPollRecords={{consumer.maxPollRecords}}"
                            + "&consumersCount={{consumer.consumersCount}}"
                            + "&seekTo={{consumer.seekTo}}"
                            + "&groupId={{consumer.group}}"
                            + "&valueDeserializer=" + BytesDeserializer.class.getName())
                            .routeId("FromKafka")
                            .process(processor)
                            .choice()
                                .when(header("kafka"))
                                    .recipientList(simple("kafka:${header.kafka[topicName]}"))
                                .end()
                                .when(header("rabbit"))
                                    .recipientList(simple("rabbit:${header.rabbit[queueName]}"))
                                .end();
                }
            };
        case "rabbit":
            return new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    // set rabbit component

                    from("rabbit")
                            .routeId("rabbit")
                            .process(processor)
                            .choice()
                                .when(header("kafka"))
                                    .recipientList(simple("kafka:${header.kafka[topicName]}"))
                                .end()
                                .when(header("rabbit"))
                                    .recipientList(simple("rabbit:${header.rabbit[queueName]}"))
                                .end();
                }
            };
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can see both the routes have the same ending, the more messages busses i add the more copy paste ill have to do....

I cant seem to find a way the make the to() dynamic ( maybe another factory? but the to() method doesnt accept routes)

If i could do the same generic to() in all my factory routes
and then in one place to manage all the to() options i have, that'll be perfect
I tried to do that with "direct:outputManager"
but then "outputManager" gotta start with a from() and i only need to resolve a to()

P.S -
Im new to camel so i accept that i might be totally off and theres a way simpler solution, ill be glad to hear it
P.S 2-
I only checked the kafka route and the rabbit one i just psodo coded it to fit this question, so i know it wont work on the rabbit part

EDIT: As Paizo suggested in the comments i explored the Endpoint direction, it looks promising
The only thing i miss is actually being able to access the message in the endpoint in order to decide which producer to return

Code:

```
.to(new DefaultEndpoint() {
                @Override
                public Producer createProducer() throws Exception {

                    // get message header and decide which producer to return
                    Producer producer;
                    //case kafka
                    producer = new KafkaProducer(new KafkaEndpoint("kafka:blaTopic",new KafkaComponent(getContext())));
                    //case rabbit - psodo code
                    producer = new RabbitProducer();

                    return producer;
                }

                @Override
                public Consumer createConsumer(Processor processor) throws Exception {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You cannot receive messages from this endpoint");
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isSingleton() {
                    return false;
                }
            })
```

Comment: you can try to use `org.apache.camel.Endpoint` as parameter for the `.to()`; Or split it further with an extra route to be more easily pluggable. Alternative is using `adviceWith` AFTER you created the route (http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) but is mostly mean for testing.

Comment: I started reading about the Endpoint and it seems like a good direction!
But the thing is when i extend DefaultEndpoint, i dont have the message in my scope, and the decision of which "produce" ill need to do is base on the exchange header of each message... and also i dont know how to specify that this producer is sending to kafka/rabbit

Comment: Have you looked in to DynamicRouter example in camel, may be this will be of some help, http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html.

Comment: Do you base the from and the to on properties, or is the destination based on something about the message?